# For loop is too slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
var Combinatorics = require('js-combinatorics');
var fs = require('fs');

cp = Combinatorics.cartesianProduct(
    ["4", "@", "/\\", "/-\\", "^", "∂", "λ", "α", "(!", "Z", "α"], ["1²", "2", "?", "P\\", "[\"/_", "l\"/_", "|-", "|2", "|?", "®", "12", "/2", "I2", "|^", "|~", "(r)", "|`", "l2", "Я", "ʁ", "я"], ["#", "(-)", ")-(", "/-/", "4", "<~>", "[-]", "\\-\\", "]-[", "]~[", "{-}", "{=}", "|-|", "|~|", "}{", ":-:", "}-{", "н"], ["!", "'", "1", "[]", "][", "|", "¦", "¡", ":", "]", "ι"], ["&", "3", "€", "£", "ë", "[-", "|=-", "ə", "ε"]
);

for(var index = 0; index < cp.length; ++index) {
    //may be not the best idea, but in this way I will add new line to each word when saving them into array
    var aux = cp.toArray()[index] + '\n';
    console.log(cp.toArray()[index])
    var contents = fs.appendFile("./output.txt", aux,
        function(error) {
            if(error) {
                console.log("error writing");
            }
        });
}
```

It will generate 411642 words and will save them from the new line"`\n`" into output.txt

This code works fast if I generate not such a big number of words, but in my case there are 411642 words to be generated and I wrote them from the newline using "`\n`" in output.txt. My speed using this code is approximative 82 words/ 1 minute. It's super slow. I don't understand why? How can I make it fast?

Comment: Welcome to the world of combinatorics.  You generate an exponentially growing result set.  Javascript is not the fastest language for this.

Comment: @EricJ. So what can I use here the easiest and fastest way of getting my wordlist)?

Comment: If you're running the loop with the console.log, remove it, it'll make it a lot faster.

Comment: Not sure why so many downvotes, it's a well-written question, and it's very clear what the OP wants...

Comment: @dandavis this console.log console.log(cp.toArray()[index]) , not the one in the appendFile callback

Comment: if `cp.toArray()` is expensive, don't run it twice per iteration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a string interpolation or create an Array and then push the values to it.

In the end, you would append the entire string, or use the `Array.prototype.join` to turn it in a string.

The `for` loop is fast, the problem there is the I/O. Take a look at the example below:

```
var Combinatorics = require('js-combinatorics');
var fs = require('fs');

var cp = Combinatorics.cartesianProduct(
  ["4", "@", "/\\", "/-\\", "^", "∂", "λ", "α", "(!", "Z", "α"],
  ["1²", "2", "?", "P\\", "[\"/_", "l\"/_", "|-", "|2", "|?", "®", "12", "/2", "I2", "|^", "|~", "(r)", "|`", "l2", "Я", "ʁ", "я"],
  ["#", "(-)", ")-(", "/-/", "4", "<~>", "[-]", "\\-\\", "]-[", "]~[", "{-}", "{=}", "|-|", "|~|", "}{", ":-:", "}-{", "н"],
  ["!", "'", "1", "[]", "][", "|", "¦", "¡", ":", "]", "ι"],
  ["&", "3", "€", "£", "ë", "[-", "|=-", "ə", "ε"]
);

fs.appendFile('./output.txt', cp.toArray().join('\n'), function(error) {
  if (error)
    console.log('Error writing ' + error);
});
```

Note: another thing I did here was to cache the `cp.toArray()` into a variable, so you don't need to call it once per loop iteration. Doing the both things (write to the file only once, and calling `.toArray()` only once either, you'll have a much better performance, completely sure.

---

**UPDATE**

I've just realized you don't need a loop at all, since the only thing you're doing is concatenating a `\n` for each word you have, and you can do that by calling the `Array.prototype.join` method.

Answer (score 0):

In any loop that uses file I/O, pretty much the very first thing you want to examine is how to minimize your file operations because that is generally orders of magnitude slower than CPU tasks.

This code is just designed wrong in a bunch of ways.  For starters don't write each word to a file one word at a time with `fs.appendFile()` called for every single word.  Open the file once.  Then use buffered I/O (like a stream) for writing so you aren't doing open, write, close on your file for every single word.  Or, collect all the words into an array and then write them all at once.

Also, you're putting an async operation in the middle of a `for` loop which will overload your system as it can't possibly start and carry out that many async operations at the same time (they will end up getting queued by the system).

Comment: Thank you, but how can I open the file once only? and how can I use buffered I/O?

Comment: @cebit933 - Uh, open the file before your loop.  Collect all the words into an array during the loop, then write them all out at the end of the loop and the close the file.  This is file I/O basics.  You could also use file streams which will buffer for you.